# QT: DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x8007007b ()

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Version 5.14.1.

When I was trying to play a video(.mp3), the program stopped working

And given error is DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x8007007b ()

```
AudioPlayer::AudioPlayer(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
, m_backgroundMusic(NULL)  //QMediaPlayer * m_backgroundMusic
{
    QUrl backgroundMusicUrl = QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/music/8bitDungeonLevel.mp3");

    if (QFile::exists(backgroundMusicUrl.toLocalFile()))
    {
        m_backgroundMusic = new QMediaPlayer(this);
        QMediaPlaylist * backgroundMusicList = new QMediaPlaylist();

        QMediaContent media(backgroundMusicUrl);
        backgroundMusicList->addMedia(media);
        backgroundMusicList->setCurrentIndex(0);

        backgroundMusicList->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::CurrentItemInLoop);
        m_backgroundMusic->setPlaylist(backgroundMusicList);

    }
}


void AudioPlayer::startBGM()
{

    if (m_backgroundMusic)
    {
        qDebug() << m_backgroundMusic;
        m_backgroundMusic->play();
    }
}
```

the output as below

```
QMediaPlayer(0x3987eb0)
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x8007007b ()
```

I search the Internet and **add LAV Filters to QT installation directory** 
, I also restart the computer but nothing changes.So how to fix it?

Comment: Could it have to do with the file you have specified. I am not aware of a directory scheme that starts with `:` in `:/music/8bitDungeonLevel.mp3`

Comment: yeah,thanks, actually when I use absolute path it works!

Comment: I will post as answer, please mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path in `QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/music/8bitDungeonLevel.mp3")` appears to be off, AFIK there is no (at least not common) path naming scheme that uses `:` to begin paths.

UPDATE:

I was told that `:/` refers to resources that have been compiled into a Qt application, I think using the [Qt Resource Compiler (rcc)](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtapplicationmanager/use-qt-resources.html)

Comment: Actually, within Qt applications, paths beginning with `:/` are recognised as resources that have been compiled into the executable itself as a Qt *resource file*. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html ... BTW I am getting a very similar error from an application I am coding for (currently on Windows + MSYS2/Mingw-w64) when I am trying to play (an external) `.mp3` files myself - haven't found a solution yet though...

Comment: @SlySven I would make a question about it then (unless you already have)! And thank you I will update

Comment: It *seems* that `DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code` covers a whole range of problems with the Windows OS / Media sub-system end of things (of course!) and the precise hex number conveys the specific details - but I haven't yet found out what those details are for the value here (or wot I wuz seeing). 8-(

Comment: @SlySven What do you mean by value?

Comment: In the OPs question the `0x8007007b` value - it is likely M$ has a list that gives the meaning for each distinct value but no-one seems to know what that is...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to load mp3 from resources:

```cpp
m_mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/Audio/MouseOver.mp3"));
```

(do no forget do delete `fromLocalFile`)